# AWK: Print first field of every line as identifier for every following field in the corresponding line

Tags: awk

I have a input file like this with a blank as field seperator

```
AAABBB: 243.234.12.2 123.3.2 231.5.12 451.192.29.9
BBXDS: 324.22.32.5 235.235.283 234.239. 234.23.23.1 
DDF: 23.12.59.09 98.39.239.29 394.293.2.2
```

The output should look like this:

```
AAABBB: 243.234.12.2
AAABBB: 123.3.2
AAABBB: 231.5.12
AAABBB: 451.192.29.9
BBXDS: 324.22.32.5
BBXDS: 235.235.283
BBXDS: 234.239.
.....
```

The first field of every line is a identifier and should be printed as a new line in front of every column in the corresponding line until the end of the line.

Comment: Really close to a duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/456907/117549

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fairly straightforwardly:

```
awk '{ for(i=2; i <= NF; i++) print $1, $i}' < input
```

On every line, loop from 2 until the last field (`N`umber of `F`ields), printing field 1 and the looped field.